# Get parent with recursive function returning None

Tags: python

I am making a function that will get the top-most parent using recursion. I must be missing some logic because it seems like it should work to me. I even print the obj.name right before returning it, but it ends up returning "None".

```
import bpy


def main():

    def get_parent_object(obj):
        parent = obj.parent
        
        if parent != None:
            get_parent_object(parent)

        else:
            print(obj.name)
            return obj
    
    selected_objects = bpy.context.selected_objects
    
    for obj in selected_objects:
        print(get_parent_object(obj))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Any help is much appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Hello! you need to `return get_parent_object(parent)`. As it stands, your function scope ends without any return statement in case `parent != None` which implicitely returns `None` in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll suggest another method that will not throw a `RecursionError` in case you have a really complicated setup with hundreds of parents.

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.active_object
ancestor = obj
while ancestor.parent is not None:
    ancestor = ancestor.parent
print(ancestor)
```